Inserting signatures in cells
Is there a way (besides inserting an image) to format a cell in Google Sheets so that when you click on the cell, it opens something that lets you sign and have your signature show up in that cell?
Inserting an image is too complicated for what I'm doing (people who aren't tech savvy will need to use this sheet, and I want it to be as simple as possible for them).

Welcome to Web Applications SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?


when you click on the cell, it opens something that lets you sign and have your signature show up in that cell?

That cannot be done, because Google specifically prohibits changes to the Google Sheets interface.
What you could do is add a button or a custom menu item that opens a sidebar or a dialog box that features some sort of HTML5 canvas that lets one write their signature. Building the functionality requires some actual programming.
Google Sheets may not be the best tool to collect signatures. There are many tools that let you do that much more easily.
